# Word that is equivalent to "easily sexually-swayed pushovers"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I looked over the Internet for a word that describes a man that is easily swayed and driven by women and their desires but I couldn't find one. I hope that you would be of help. Even if it's a phrase..

Comment: You may want to [edit] your question to include an example of a sentence where you would like to use this word or phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something euphemistic like

> He is susceptible to the *charms of a woman*.

or something less subtle

> He is a [horndog](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=horndog).

though horndog may have predator connotations.

Depends on who's the hunted, and who's the huntee.